# Adding row- and columnmajor matrix

Tags: c++

I would like to make a loop in C++ that adds two matrices where the first is a stored as a row major and the second is stored as a column major. I am however not sure what the mathematical relation between the indices will be. I tried to do it for a 3x3 matrix. In this case the permutation of indices looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 3 6 1 4 7 2 5 8
```

Can I write this in closed form when iterating like:

```
A[i]+B[f(i)]
```

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, the following is the conclusive formula:

```
f(i) = 3 * (i % 3) + (i / 3);
```

Here `i` is regard as the iterative index of the first matrix, which as is stored as a row major, the corresponded position of the index is `(i / 3, i % 3)`.

So the second matrix, which as is stored as a column major, the corresponded position is `(i % 3, i / 3)` by swap row and column number.

As `Index = 3 * row + column`, so in conclusion, the iterative index of the second matrix, represented as `f(i)`,  is `3 * (i % 3) + (i / 3)`.

Comment: Plus one, my solution simplifies to this for 3 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of rows in the first matrix is *r* and the number of columns is *c*, then

```
f(i) = i / r + i % c * r
```

where I'm exploiting *integer division* for the first term and the *associativity* of `%` and `*` being from left to right in the second term (`%` and `*` have the same *precedence*).

Comment: You could just have included parentheses instead of explaining about the associativity (+1 regardless, but just saying).

Comment: Personally I dislike excess parentheses with a vengeance. Learn that damn table like you learn your times tables as a child! It's my little dogmatic indulgence. But your comment has validity for more rational folk, I concur.

Comment: I happen to know that table pretty well myself (I think), but still use parens. Unlike a multiplication table, there is a good workaround to forgetting :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to explicitly calculate the formula for the permutation of the indeces is to consider the distance of the elements belonging to the same row in the column major stored matrix:

```
// given rows and cols as the number of rows and columns of the matrices

size_t max_index = rows * cols - 1;

for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; i <= max_index; ++i ) {
    c_rm[i] = a_rm[i] + b_cm[j];
    j += rows;
    if ( j > max_index )
        j -= max_index;
}
```

this may be faster then calculating an integer division a reminder and a multiplication for each index value.

Comment: Are you a numpy dev?

Comment: @MadPhysicist no, I'm sorry... Why?

Comment: Just the sort of optimization that numpy devs are interested in. What you have here is a very rudimentary version of how numpy treats n-dimensional arrays.